# Message: Non-static method statistics_model::compensations_per_day() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, open-source

I'm Currently working on an open source system that have this error in the manager account in retrieving the day summary

```
    <?php
$this->load->model('statistics_model');

//.date("Y-m-j",strtotime($date))
foreach(statistics_model::compensations_per_day() as $data){
    echo "
        <tr >
        <td  style='text-align: center'>$data->time_constraint</td>
        <td  style='text-align: center'>$data->number</td>
        </tr>
        ";
}
?>
```

Comment: How could we possibly know? Are you using a facade or something similar in order to execute your functions as static? We need to see the `statistics_model` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess.

```
foreach($this->statistics_model->compensations_per_day() as $data)
```

It would appear that the compensations_per_day method cannot be accessed statically.

See https://github.com/davidadamojr/openbooth/blob/master/application/controllers/manager/pdf.php

And 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

You should declare as "static function compensations_per_day()" so then you can call it in that way that you want